# Firebase Security Rules how to wildcard all path except the ones specified

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Let's imagine a set of rules having the following fields:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /stories/{story} {}
     match /comments/{comment} {}
     match /posts/{post} {}
  }
}
```

And we want to add a new match condition for all the remaining collections using a wildcard of come sort.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is possible now thanks to the "path to string" coercing. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using recursive wildcards that was introduced in Firestore Rules **version 2** recently. But you need to specify rules version like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Matches any document in collection and subcollections
    match /{path=**} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

More details you can find here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards

Comment: This will not work, because the recursive wildcard will match *all* collections, even the ones that the OP doesn't want matched.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is not possible.  If you use a wildcard in a match on a collection like this:

```
match /{collection}/{doc} { ... }
```

Then it will match all documents in all collections, including stories, comments, and posts.  This is certainly not what you want.  There's no way to do substring or regex matching with a wildcard.  It always applies to an entire collection or document ID in the path.

Comment: Exactly that's what I saw, it's too bad if you want to perform queries based on variables like languages.. Let's say collection have language name, then you could automatically generate a query based on the navigator one, but it just throws an error and blocks your app.... Bad for UX :)

Comment: That's not really how collections are intended to be used in Firestore.  If you have any sort of unrestricted variability in your database (that is to say, non-discrete sets of possible values), you should code those values into the fields of your documents instead, and use those values as filters in your queries.

Comment: Of course yes; anyway, I just built another array field to filter known languages

Comment: This is possible now thanks to the "path to string" coercing. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I've came across this recently and I've come up with a solution. Wildcards (non-recursive) can be not only at document level, but also at collection name level.

A solution to your example could be:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{collection}/{docName}/{document=**} {
         allow read: if collection == 'comments';
         allow write: if collection != 'posts';
    }
  }
}
```

Just as an example, I hope I've been clear

Answer (score 1):

Needed that for my project and I've solved it by utilizing `request.path` and adding exceptions for paths that I needed to exclude from wildcards:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if <condition> && !isExcludedPath();
        }
        match /stories/{story} {}
        match /comments/{comment} {}
        match /posts/{post} {}



        function excludedCollections(){
            return ["stories", "comments", "posts"]
        }

        function pathContainsAny(pathArray){
            return string(request.path).split("/").hasAny(pathArray)
        }
        function isExcludedPath(){
            return pathContainsAny(excludedCollections())
        }
    }
}
```

`string(request.path)` - this coercing, which is vital for this approach, was introduced pretty recently, so if you get an error here, upgrade your `firebase-tools` to the latest version